# Why does setState cause too many re-rendering when pushing a new element to an array state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a code that listens to a server-side event, grabs the event data as object, and pushes it to a state array. However, at the moment I am directly updating the array instead of setting the state via `setState`. Otherwise, I'd get a "too many re-rendering" error.

```
const App = () => {
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);
  console.log(records);
  const newRecord = useDataListener({
    eventName: "message",
    srcURL: "http://localhost:5001/status_stream"
  });

  // If change into the following lines, code won't work
  // if (newRecord !== null) {
  //   setRecords(oldRecords => [newRecord, ...oldRecords])
  //}

  // But this looks incorrect, despite being able to render content
  if (newRecord !== null) {
    records.unshift(newRecord);
  }

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Header />
      <PaginationBar />
      {records.map((x, i) => (
        <SummaryLog key={records.length - (i + 1)} record={x} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Does anyone see why using `setRecords` could cause too much re-rendering? Thanks!!

Comment: How does useDataListener work? Is it active at all times, can you pass a call-back to it?

Comment: Sorry try to add a code snippet in comments but failed. Yeah it is a hook listens to server side event. I put it in a codesandbox here (as in `hooks.js`; ignore other files, please):
https://codesandbox.io/embed/keen-cherry-pfj1c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `useEffect` hook with `newRecord` dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
   setRecords(oldRecords => [...oldRecords, newRecord])
  }, [newRecord]);
```

Comment: `useEffect` is run, only when its dependencies' values changes, by definition. @ShanDou

Comment: `useEffect()` is a React hook that will trigger some logic N number of times depending on how you set it up. The second argument of `useEffect()`accepts an array. If the array is empty, it will only run once. But, if you pass in a dependency hence "newRecord" it subscribes to that value, and will re-run the logic inside of it whenever that value has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mutate the `records`. State should be immutable.

Also, fetching data is a side effect. So use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to handle side effects.

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    setRecords(oldRecords => ([...oldRecords, newRecord]))
  }
  , [newRecord]
);
```

This hook will only run if there are `newRecord`s.